# Upload a file via ftp using php, JS & ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, ftp

I am having a hard time getting a simple file uploaded to my remote server from my desktop.  I have a simple form in php to get the file:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
        <td><label>select the file to reconcile the checks</label></td>
        <td><input type="file" id="file" name="file" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="checks" value="Check Reconciliation" /></td>    
    </tr>
</form>
```

Which is then passed to my JavaScript with:

```
$("#checks").live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkReconciliation3.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: ({file: $('#file').val()}),
        success: function(data){
            $('#message').html(data.message);
        }
    });
}); //end of checks click function
```

and `checkReconciliation3.php` is:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once ('../db.php');
require_once('ftp.php');
$file = $_POST['file'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

//ftp_chdir($conn_id, '/home/bookcell/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/');
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY);

echo $php_errormsg;
ftp_close($conn_id); // close the connection
```

From everything I have researched on SO, this looks to be correct, but I keep getting the following errors:

`PHP Warning:  ftp_put(checkslastmonth.csv) [<a href='function.ftp-put'>function.ftp-put</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /chroot/home/bookcell/bookcellaronline.com/html/testbcos/accounting/checkReconciliation3.php` on line 24.

Line 24 is

```
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_BINARY);
```

I have tried is using `$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"]` and I still get the same error.  The file that I want to upload to my server is located on my desktop. How do I get this to work??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

file upload is not possible through ajax.
you can do this through iframe, if you don't want to refresh the page.
http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Comment: You certainly can upload files via ajax.  Any browser that supports the File API can upload files via XHR level 2.

Comment: @Yordi This is not true you can upload files with ajax. Almost all HTML5 browsers can do this.

Comment: AJAX is possible. I would probably still implement this with a hidden iframe though as you will get wider compatibility. Ajax will only work IE10+. In my opinion you can create the same effect with the iframe so you might as well cover more browsers.

Comment: You lose quite a bit with the iframe approach, such as: upload progress, the ability to manipulate the file client-side and then upload the modified version, custom headers, etc.  The best approach is to use XHR where supported, and the iframe approach only where absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using XHR2 in any browser that supports the File API (all but IE9 and older, for the most part).  If your browser does not support the File API, you will need to resort to submitting a form inside an iframe.

There are pre-built solutions for you that will handle these tasks, and much more.  I suggest checking out one, [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) which handles this task cross-browser and provides additional features you might find useful, such as chunking, auto-resume, paste to upload, drag and drop support, etc.  Server-side examples are also provided.  Full Disclosure: I maintain Fine Uploader.